# I don't understand this arithmetic on Java

Tags: java, math

I was doing a java tutorial when I typed this in:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 5;
int d = -a*b/c*a;
System.out.println(d);
```

The output was `-6`. However when I use a calculator, I get `-36/5` based on the left to right precedence rule. Can someone please explain why there are different answers?

Comment: when you divide to `int`s, the result is an `int`.

Comment: Also note the precedence: `-3*4/5*3` -> `((-12/5)*3)` -> `-2 * 3` -> `-6`.

Comment: Thanks @MarounMaroun . I understand now. I thought int extracted only the integer after the final answer and not during the calculation process.

Answer (score 2):

Try it again with doubles:

```
double a = 3;
double b = 4;
double c = 5;
double d = -a*b/c*a;
System.out.println(d);
```

The problem is that the division will convert the result to an `int`

Comment: I got -7.1999999999999999999999999999 which still isn't -6 when considering int taking only the integer.